# When does $\mathbb{E}(X \log_2{X}) = \Theta(\mathbb{E}(X) \log_2(\mathbb{E}(X))$?

Tags: probability, asymptotics

For discrete random variable $X$ taking values from the range $\{1,\dots,n\}$, when does $\mathbb{E}(X \log_2{X}) = \Theta(\mathbb{E}(X) \log_2(\mathbb{E}(X))$?

By Jensen's inequality I think that $\mathbb{E}(X \log_2{X}) \geq \mathbb{E}(X) \log_2(\mathbb{E}(X))$ as $f(X) = X \log_2{X}$ is a convex function.  This answers half of the question.

As an example, if $X$ is uniform then it seems that $\mathbb{E}(X \log_2{X}) \sim \mathbb{E}(X) \log_2(\mathbb{E}(X))$.

Comment: If $X$ is non-negative, how to define $X \log_2 X$ for $X=0$? As zero?

Comment: @Sasha Fixed, thanks.

Comment: What is $\Theta$ ?

Comment: @StephaneLaurent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: Ok I didn't know this notation... but there's no "$n$" here, so I don't understand.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Added explicit $n$ to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general since if $\mathbb P(X=1)=1-\frac1n$ and $\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac1n$ then $\mathbb E(X\log X)=\log n$ while $\mathbb E(X)\log\mathbb E(X)\to2\log2$.

In the other direction, if $a\mathbb P(X=k)\leqslant\mathbb P(X=i)\leqslant b\mathbb P(X=k)$ for some given positive and finite $a$ and $b$, uniformly on $k\leqslant n$, $i\leqslant n$, and $n$, then the result probably holds.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "uniformly on $k \leq n, i \leq n$".

Comment: For some a and b independent of k, i, n.

Comment: Is this the same as saying that all the probabilities are within a constant factor of each other?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Oh that's quite a conservative set of probability distributions!

Comment: Yes, motivated by the counterexample at the beginning of the answer.